# Do you have problems updating permissions on hasura v 2 alpha 8?

Tags: graphql, hasura

I recently updated my database to v2 and am now running on alpha 8, the thing is I can't seem to update column permissions, when I try to it loads and does nothing. Is there a way to log all these updates to see why it doesn't update? Any feedback is really appreciated, thanks. :)

Comment: What database are you using Postgres or MS Server?

Comment: Could you provide some more details? may be the exact steps that you followed. and are you getting any error messages?

-- To enable logging : https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/deployment/logging.html

-- I think you could also try validating the permission that you created from the exported metadata (from Hasura console > settings) https://hasura.io/docs/latest/graphql/core/migrations/manage-metadata.html#exporting-hasura-metadata

Comment: I am currently using postgres as my database, I did the little work around using sooraj's validation, I edited my permissions on the json metadata and re-uploaded it with the permissions I required.

Comment: My point is why are you using hasura v2.0 ... it is in its testing phase and not stable. The reason I asked you about your DB is, if you are using Postgres try to use hasura v1.3.3 it is their stable version. I have used the hasura v2.0 alpha 8 for some project using MS Server as DB, and it has a lot of problems even they only offer the select permission.

Answer (score 1):

Faced similar problem tried deleting that particular permission and adding again worked for me

Comment: I had a similar problem, after adding an aggregate permission, my aggregate query would fail roughly half the time. I deleted the permission and added it again (uncheck "Allow role user to make aggregation queries" and check "Allow role user to make aggregation queries"), and then it works 100%